# C# Downloading HTML from a website after logging in

Tags: c#, logging, web, navigation, browser

I've recently been looking on how to get data from a website using C#. I tried using the WebBrowser object to navigate and log in, and that worked fine, but I keep getting the same problem over and over again: when I navigate to the wanted page I get disconnected.

I've tried several things like making sure that only one HtmlDocument exists but I still get logged out.

TLDR: how do you stay logged in, from page to page, while navigating a website with WebBrowser? *Or are there better alternatives?*

EDIT: So far I have the following code;

```
currentWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
currentWebBrowser.DocumentText = @"<head></head><body></body>";
currentWebBrowser.Url = new Uri("about:blank");
currentWebBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com");

HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
Req.Proxy = null;
Req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpWebResponse Res = (HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse();

currentWebBrowser.Document.Cookie = Res.Cookies.ToString();
```

At which moment should I get the cookies? And is my code correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have to preserve the cookies returned from your login request and reuse those cookies on all subsequent requests - the authentication cookie tells the server that you are in fact logged in already. E.g. see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/00a29544-8cf4-4de2-8e7c-e7931b0e2221) on how to do that.